# How to merge 2 associative arrays with foreach in systemverilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm trying to merge 2 string type's associative arrays with foreach() https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496838/20066803

```
module test;
         
bit [31:0] arrayA[string];             
bit [31:0] arrayB[string];             
bit [31:0] arrayC[string];             
         
initial begin
arrayA["GOOD_PKT"]=7; 
arrayA["BAD_PKT"]=9;  
         
arrayB = '{"apple":5 , "orrange":6};   
         
foreach(arrayA[i]) begin
arrayC[i] = arrayA[i];
$display("arrayC[%0s]=%h", i, arrayC[i]);
end      
         
foreach(arrayC[i]) begin
arrayC[i] = arrayB[i]; 
$display("arrayC[%0s] = %0h", i, arrayC[i]);
end

/* This not work.
foreach(arrayC[i]) begin    
arrayC[i] = arrayB[i](arrayC);
$display("arrayC[%0s] = %0h", i, arrayC[i]);
end
*/

/* This not work.
arrayC = {arrayA,arrayB};
*/
```

I got only 2 elements

```
arrayC[BAD_PKT]=00000009
arrayC[GOOD_PKT]=00000009
```

but I expected 4 elements

```
arrayC[BAD_PKT]=00000009
arrayC[GOOD_PKT]=00000009
arrayC[apple]=00000005
arrayC[orange]=00000006
```

How to merge 2 associative arrays with foreach() in systemverilog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in your code, the second `foreach` use `arrayC`
try this:

```
foreach(arrayA[i]) begin
    arrayC[i] = arrayA[i];
    $display("arrayC[%0s]=%h", i, arrayC[i]);
end      
         
foreach(arrayB[i]) begin
    arrayC[i] = arrayB[i]; 
    $display("arrayC[%0s] = %0h", i, arrayC[i]);
end
```

Comment: Is it possible to merge without foreach()?

Comment: I haven't figured out how to do this, and haven't found the answer in the SV standard. I recommend using macros to simplify your code

Answer (score 0):

In the second `foreach`, you go over `arrayC`, not `arrayB` -- probably a typo? If you change it, you should get what you want. Of course, if the two arrays have overlapping elements, you will only keep the last one you add, but you will have to deal with that separately (for instance, by using `.exists()`).